# What's the best application server for Grails Applications Deployment?

Tags: java, spring, grails, deployment, glassfish

I've been studying several application servers to deploy my Grails applications. I discovered that some solutions are too complex for receiving simple applications.

What are your experiences in deploying applications?

Glassfish is a good solution or you prefer another?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for light weight I would suggest Tomcat.  Glassfish has a lot of issues if you're using it on Windows and using the autodeploy feature.  Running on a linux server and not using the autodeploy feature Glassfish seems to work reasonably well, you'll probably want to bump up the memory though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get it. Grails uses Spring, wich doesn't need any Application server to run.

If you need an application server for other needs, just avoid Webshere or Weblogic. Other ones have pros and cons that are not specially related to Grails.

Comment: Oups, I'm totally wrong. The doc says to NOT use run-app, but deploy the war.
http://grails.org/Deployment